# JMeter: Passing Key Value Pairs Not Working

Tags: api, jmeter

I'm using JMeters to automate API testing to/from our database using basic CRUD methodology. After the record creation, I'm trying to perform 3 different types of Reads (think CRRRUD). :)

**Read 1** - Retrieve by ID 
HTTP (GET) the base URL is appended with the saved record ID.

```
http..../crud/tableName/${newRecordId}
```

This returns

**Read 2** - Retrieve by field type with no defined value
HTTP (POST) the base URL is extended with a "search" as the end. A Key is defined ("name") with no value.

```
http..../crud/tableName/search
Parameter Name = name
Value = {undefined}
```

This returns all records within the table whose field ("name") is not null.

**Read 3** - Retrieve by field type with a defined value
HTTP (POST) the base URL is extended with a "search" as the end. A Key is defined ("name") with the value generated during the creation request.

```
http..../crud/tableName/search
Parameter Name = name
Value = Metropolis
```

This, too, returns ALL of the records within the table instead of just the record(s) whose name = Metropolis.

This 3rd Retrieve works properly when using a REST client, (e.g., Postman, Advanced REST Client, etc.) when defining the Key|Value pair as "name|Metropolis". So it must be something within JMeter that I'm missing.

Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one correct answer: compare what's being sent by REST Client and JMeter using sniffer tool (i.e. [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)), detect the differences and configure JMeter accordingly.

Just a guess: given you mentioned "API" an "REST" words maybe you need to pass it as JSON like:

```
{"name":"Metropolis"}
```

as a single parameter value

[image: Single parameter]

or in formatted way (in case if server checks Content-Length and/or wants the request to be properly formatted)

[image: Body Data]

You may also need to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) in order to send `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`. See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: But what if you don't know the value of name? I'm trying to pass in the value from what was generated and save to a variable.  **{"name", ${fieldNameValue}}** Where key = "name" and value = ${fieldNameValue}. I can't see to find a way to do this.

Comment: You're almost there, just surrond variable with quotation marks `{"name":"${fieldNameValue}"`

Comment: Once again, you rock! That was exactly what I was missing. Thanks!